# Conditional While loops with array comparison

Tags: c, linux, while-loop, debian

I'm reading values into an array which are then getting checked against for a specific system protocol, upon which if the conditions are not satisfied, the program must continue reading, simple enough. The code block:

```
buff = read(fp, token_monger, MAX_APDU);
printf("the token_monger[2] and token_monger[3] = %02x and %02x\n", token_monger[2], token_monger[3]);

while(token_monger[2] != 0x01 && token_monger[3] != 0x00)
{
    printf("inside while token check\n");
    buff = read(fp, token_monger, MAX_APDU);
    token_monger[buff] = 0;
}

printf("the token_monger[2] and token_monger[3] = %02x and %02x\n", token_monger[2], token_monger[3]);
```

the prints before and after the while loop are there for debugging. they are both printing a value of 0x00. When I execute this code, the process reaches before and after the loop but never enters it, I know from my prints that the conditions are not satisfied, furthermore, there is an if statement just a few lines down that should also be satisfied when the program exits the while loop (if anyone would like to see that portion, I can post). I was wondering if there is anything glaringly obvious that I am doing wrong, or if this is a possible issue with the compiler and not being able to handle something like this (which seems highly unlikely) thanks again

Comment: You have called your file descriptor `fp` which makes me suspect that it's a `FILE *` instead of an `int`, so you didn't post the relevant code, you need to post code that reproduces the problem, in your code declarations are missing and the context is missing too, so it's impossible to help you.

Comment: When you say "they are both printing a value of 0x00. ", do you mean that both token_monger[2] and token_monger[3] are both 0x00, both before and after the loop?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote ".. before .. the while loop .. they are both .. 0x00. "
The while loop is only entered when

```
while(token_monger[2] != 0x01 && token_monger[3] != 0x00)
```

As you said, `token_monger[3] == 0x00`, so the while loop is skipped.

Comment: && is AND. `while (true && false)` results in `while (false)`. You can use || when you want OR. I hope the loop will not be endless than.